# receive messages in the console program from the gcc compiler

Tags: c++, g++

Many lessons on compilation use the terminal.
There are warnings, compilation progress, errors.
I wanna send arguments from the console program to the program g++.exe.
And in the same place receive all messages from g++ and show using std::cout.

Comment: Could you elaborate, maybe with some examples? At the moment, it seems you are talking about "typing".

Comment: To me it sounds like you want to start a new program from your app. A first start is using the [`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function to open it in a new console window.

Comment: I compile well using the terminal. But from my own console application I get denied access in Windows 10. Even if I use the Libexecstream library.  http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It looks like you want to use a program to compile another program. You could call std::system (mentioned above) and pipe the output of gcc into your program.